# Conversion problems: CSV and adding FSC Grid Refernces to a project

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

I am trying to add a CSV layer to a base map that I have set to EPSG: 29903. The CSV file contains latitude and longitude data with no known projection. When I import this data through the add layer CSV, it projects the points somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean. I can't seem to re-project or re-calculate this to display in the correct location in EPSG: 29903 (Ireland).

At one stage, I managed to use the FSC plugin to add the points and have them displayed correctly. However, this was only available as a temporary scratch layer and I couldn't save it to a GPKG. I had to restart QGIS and when I re-opened the file, the layers had been removed. I repeated the process but am now getting the following error pop out:

QGIS version: 3.22.8-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: 8d5e9761df
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.5.0
GEOS version: 3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.0.1, June 15th, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: e64939)
Algorithm started at: 2023-07-13T10:41:56
Algorithm 'Add GRs to layers' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'GRYPE' : 1, 'INPUT' : 'Note, I have removed this line for privacy', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/Note I have removed this as well for privacy.gpkg', 'PRECISIONS' : [4,6,9], 'PREFIX' : '' }

Starting processing algo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Note: I have removed this line for privacy", line 216, in processAlgorithm
pt = geom.centroid().asPoint()
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.

Execution failed after 0.06 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Add GRs to layers' finished

Please can anybody help with this?

Comment: set your CSV file to EPSG:4326 during the import

Comment: Thanks, I already did that but it didn't work

Comment: Post a sample coordinate pair from the CSV file (plus the field names) please.